# Many files in folder - time difference while accessing file with fullpath

Tags: files, time

Folder /var/log/something may have  1 file (test.log) in it or 1000000 different files (and test.log of course).
Is there a time difference while accessing file test.log with realpath between those two amounts of files?

for example:

```
less /val/log/something/test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your filesystem and how it manages directories, but modern filesystems (including ext4) will have an indexed directory structure; so accessing one file in that directory should be quite fast whether there's one or a million files in that directory.

There will be *some* variation, but not enough to really matter.

Obtaining a list of the files in the directory is another matter entirely, as then the entire index tree needs to be walked.

Comment: Ok,Thx for that :) . Are You aware of how unix is parsing the file realpath? 
Is the whole path a one , single memory pointer (etc.)
or it's a bunch of pointers (or inodes address)

Comment: All realpath does is canonicalize the name by removing `./` sequences, resolving `../` parts, and following symlinks. All of that has nothing to do with how many files are in the resulting directory. Your "example" `less /val/log/something/test.log` also doesn't have anything to do with realpath, so I don't know what you're really asking by supplying that example...

Comment: Sorry, You are right. By using realpath I meant fullpath (from OS root folder).

Comment: The inode that belongs to the file has to be found. Directories are also inodes. The directory tree is descended one by one (each time performing a lookup for a subdirectory, which in all sane filesystems does some kind of a tree search, meaning a logarithmic dependence on the number of file entries). The last lookup finds the inode of the file (and again, lookup time should increase logarithmically with the number of files in a directory). Thus, a full path lookup may take a tiny bit more time (walking the parent branches) than a relative lookup, but shouldn't be noticeable.